# Can't reset button color via javascript CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I can change the color of a button in javascript using the CSS backgroundImage linear-gradient, that works but it does not work when I use the same technique to try to reset back to the original state.

What am I missing?

```js
var darkened=false;

function toggle() {

  if (darkened) {
      console.log("lightening button");
      document.getElementById("scrollbutton").style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(rgb(222, 222, 222), rgb(255, 255, 255));";

  } else {

      console.log("darkening button");
      document.getElementById("scrollbutton").style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(rgb(99, 99, 99), rgb(166, 166, 166))";
  }

  darkened = ! darkened;

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(222, 222, 222),rgb(255, 255, 255));" id="scrollbutton" onclick="toggle();"> pressme</button>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't have to put semi-colons after doing a css function such as linear-gradient**

*Because , javascript assumes it is the semicolon for its statement and end the code right there*

```js
var darkened=false;

function toggle() {

  if (darkened) {
      console.log("lightening button");
      document.getElementById("scrollbutton").style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(rgb(222, 222, 222), rgb(255, 255, 255))";

  } else {

      console.log("darkening button");
      document.getElementById("scrollbutton").style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(rgb(99, 99, 99), rgb(166, 166, 166))";
  }

  darkened = ! darkened;

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(222, 222, 222),rgb(255, 255, 255));" id="scrollbutton" onclick="toggle();"> pressme</button>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need not need to define a variable and change the inline style. You can use `classList.toggle` and separate style and add them in new class

```js
function toggle() {
  document.getElementById("scrollbutton").classList.toggle('darkening');
}
```

```css
.lightening {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(222, 222, 222), rgb(255, 255, 255));
}

.darkening {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(99, 99, 99), rgb(166, 166, 166))
}
```

```html
<button class="lightening" id="scrollbutton" onclick="toggle();"> pressme</button>
```